# List positions without brackets

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list l which contains the indices of some array a. For instance,

```
l = {{1,1},{1,2}}
a = {{a11,a12},{a21,a22}}
```

I want to access the elements of a at the positions given by l, i.e. in this case I want to access

```
a[[1,1]] = a11 
a[[1,2]] = a12
```

However, I cannot simply feed the elements of l into the a with double brackets:

```
In[1]:= a[[{1, 1}]]
Out[2]= {{a11, a12}, {a11, a12}}
```

Is there an easy way to remove the curly brackets in the entry of the list? It should be generalizable to much bigger arrays (so not something like `a[[l[[1,1]],l[[1,2]]]] = a11`).

Comment: [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) might be a useful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Sequence` does the job for you:

```
a[[Sequence @@ l[[1]]]]
(* a11 *)
```

Equivalently, without (most) brackets, call it `Part`:

```
Part[a, Sequence @@ l[[1]]]
(* a11 *)
```