# How to write correctly some arguments in SparseArray

Tags: sparse-arrays

I am struggling to put an argument in `SparseArray`. Let's consider the following example

```
dim = 9;
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I, Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, dim}, 0.0]
```

This works correctly and generates a matrix 9x9 with two diagonals having the value 2.0. Now I want to change some values on one of those diagonals, or better said, when I define `s` I would like to have a different value of 2.0 but only on some certain positions of that diagonal. For that I use an array `lt` specifying those positions in `s`,
`lt={3,6};`, because one can specify manually a value for a certain position (for example `{1,1}->4.0`) and I tried to put the following `Row[Flatten[Table[{i,i+1}->0.0,{i,lt}],1],","]`, having

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I,Row[Flatten[Table[{i, i + 1} -> 0.0, {i, lt}], 1], ","], Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, 
   dim}, 0.0]
```

but it failed, but If I put manually the positions

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I,{3,4}->0.0,{6,7}->0.0, Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, 
   dim}, 0.0]
```

it works. Of course this example is small and I can write it manually, but in real nb dimensions are bigger, that is why I use a `Table` command. Maybe the question could be also seen as how to obtain the output of `Table` without `{}`. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I think instead of `Row` you want `Sequence`: `SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I, 
  Sequence @@ Flatten[Table[{i, i + 1} -> 0.0, {i, lt}], 1], 
  Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, dim}, 0.0]` -- `Flatten` may be omitted; it does nothing in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelE2 for your comment. Your line code does the job well. You could put it as an answer. I noticed that you use ```Sequence``` and watching this question [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126755/list-positions-without-brackets] I think they are related

Comment: Yep, `Sequence` does the same thing in that one. It is basically for threading arguments into slots, and `Sequence @@ list` will insert a list into a sequence of slots (that is, function arguments).

Comment: To add to the comment by @MichaelE2 : `Row` should never be used as a programming construct. It's meant purely for typesetting output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
dim = 7;
lt = 2;
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I, 
    Sequence @@ Table[{i, i + 1} -> 0.0, {i, lt}], 
    Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, dim}, 0.0];

s // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
s2 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1.0 + I, Band[{2, 1}] -> 2.0, 
    Band[{lt + 1, lt + 2}] -> 2.0}, {dim, dim}, 0.0];

s == s2
(*  True  *)
```